# ImmutebleJS in Redux - reducer get error "state.push is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js, react-redux

Hi i try start learn use ImmutableJS in React. But i froze. When i try use List in my reducer i have this error  "state.push is not a function"

Here is mi code:

```
    import { List, Map} from 'immutable'
    import {FETCH_CONSTRAINTS, SET_AMOUNT_VALUE, SET_TERM_VALUE} from "../actions/actions";

export default function calculator(state = List(), action){
switch (action.type){
  case FETCH_CONSTRAINTS:
    return  state.push(Map({
       constraints: action.constraints}));
   default:
     state
  }
}
```

i don´t understand where is a problem

Comment: You're missing `return` in your default case--that might be the problem.. what output do you get it you console.log state before calling push?

Comment: It's definitely the return, because the return is missing, it gets an `undefined` which is set as state when the store is initialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, already I came with was a mistake. An example has been simplified, and yes I miss you return there. But in my code, I called other actions and they do not use immutable. All day long I had it in the eyes and I was blind. But also thanks to you I solved this.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed 2 issues in your code:

1- the initial state should be instance from Immutable List `new List()`

2- return statement in `switch->default`

```
import { List, Map} from 'immutable'
import {FETCH_CONSTRAINTS, SET_AMOUNT_VALUE, SET_TERM_VALUE} from "../actions/actions";

export default function calculator(state = new List(), action){
switch (action.type){
  case FETCH_CONSTRAINTS:
    return  state.push(Map({
       constraints: action.constraints}));
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

I Hope this help.